# How do I multiply a number (e.g., 10) by another (e.g., 3) multiple times?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

How do I multiply one number by another multiple times?

For example, **how would I multiply $10$ by $3$, one-hundred times?**

Comment: Multiply the answer 30 times.

Comment: The verb is "multiply", not "times". Thus, you would say "multiply 10 by 3". This is important particularly in a context when you're using the word "times" for a different (though related) meaning.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: multiply 10 by 3. And keep multiplying the answer. 30 times.

Comment: so 10 x 3 = 30. 30 x 3= 90 and so on.

Comment: For once I think "put on hold as unclear" is very well justified. There are a few different ways this question could be interpreted, $10 \times 3^{100}$ is just one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean
$$
10 \times 3 \times 3 \times \cdots \times 3
$$
where there are $100$ threes.

That's just
$$
10 \times 3^{100} .
$$

Many calculators will do that for you. You can type

```
10 * 3^100
```

in the Google search bar and get an answer in scientific notation.

The exact answer will have about 50 digits. There are computer programs that will find it for you.

Comment: Thank you. As you can clearly tell I'm not a mathematician (far from it) and your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean multiply $10$ by $3$ one-hundred times, the result will be $10\cdot$ $3^{100}$. The exact result is $5153775207320113310364611297656212727021075220010$, a 49-digit number. (I got this off of Wolfram-Alpha).

Otherwise, if you meant doing $10\cdot3$ one-hundred times, you will write the expression "$10\cdot3$" one-hundred times.